# Is there a way to automate xml.version?

Tags: java, xml, maven, dom, xpath

Imagine that I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<colors>
    <color1> Blue</color1>
    <color2> Red</color2>
</colors>
```

is there a way to auto set version with the version of my pom.xml project?

Suppose my pom.xml is like:

```
<groupId>br.com.colors/groupId>
<artifactId>colors</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
```

xml verision shoud be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0.2" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<colors>
     <color1> Blue</color1>
     <color2> Red</color2>
</colors>
```

Comment: The version in your XML has nothing at all to do with the pom dependency version.  Leave the xml version at 1.0.

Comment: I need to version my xml, however I wanted to stop versioning manually

Comment: But the version "attrbute" in the xml declaration is the wrong place for this. Either your document conforms to the XML 1.0 specification, and then the version should be 1.0. Or your document conforms to the XML 1.1 specification and then the version should be 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

That version is not what you imagine it means.

Versioning should be in your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<colors version="1.0.2">
     <color1>Blue</color1>
     <color2>Red</color2>
</colors>
```

You'll need a Maven task or plug in that can modify the files for you.

Personally, I'd advise against it.  Let your GitHub or source code management tool handle versioning.

You seem to want the object that is parsing your XML into a DOM tree to validate the version.  Can you describe what that looks like?  What do valid and invalid version scenarios look like?  What does the XML process do with that attribute?